# Mvc route invalid when using get

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am trying to get MVC to produce a correct url.

Right now it turns out like this:
http://domain.com/Live/Schedule?date=2013-03-29

It should of course produce it correctly like this:
http://domain.com/Live/Schedule/2013-03-29

My Global.Asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "LiveSchedule", // Route name
url: "Live/{action}/{date}", // URL with parameters
defaults: new { controller = "Live", action = "Schedule", date = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The code on the webpage that triggers the request:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Schedule", "Live", FormMethod.Get))
{
<div>
    Specify a date: @Html.DropDownList("date", Model.SelectedDateList) <input type="submit" value="Display"/>
</div>
}
```

Result:

```
<form action="/Live/Schedule" method="get">                    
<div>
Select a date: <select id="date" name="date"><option value="2013-03-27">27 onsdag</option>
<option value="2013-03-28">28 torsdag</option>
<option selected="selected" value="2013-03-29">29 fredag</option>
<option value="2013-03-30">30 l&#246;rdag</option>
<option value="2013-03-31">31 s&#246;ndag</option>
...
</select> <input type="submit" value="Display"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Controller that accepts the input:

```
public ActionResult Schedule(string date)
{
    var model = getModel(date);
    return View(model);
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you are get mixed up on is, it is regular HTML that is generating the get url, not a function of ASP.NET MVC.

As the specifications ([RFC1866](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt), page 46; [HTML 4.x](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.4) section 17.13.3) state:

> If the method is "get" and the action is an HTTP URI, the user agent
>   takes the value of action, appends a `?' to it, then appends the form
>   data set, encoded using the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
>   content type.